# OSX 10.8.2 Wiki Server file and database locations?

Tags: macos, filesystems, mysql, wiki, osx-server

OSX 10.8.2 with the Server.app installed.

Wiki server running.

where do these files live? (so that I can customize the CSS as well as back everything up.)

What databases so I need to backup and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out most everything is hosted in Postgres and not that customisable much beyond the functions they already allow.

Answer (score 1):

Does this Apple note help? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5585

Or this? http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/WikiServerAdmin_v10.6.pdf

The location seems to be (see Chapter 6 of PDF, in 2d link) /Library/Collaboration/

OK, looking specifically for 10.8.x, I find this: /Library/Server/Wiki/FileData from here https://discussions.apple.com/message/20876865#20876865

Comment: /Library/Collaboration/ doesn't exist on 10.8

Comment: neither does /System/Library/Collaboration/, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

By looking around in the Server.app package I found some relevant files here:

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/private/etc/collabd
```

The wiki server runs as process `collabd` and is a child of `ruby` and is located in:

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin/collabd
```

Oh and look, here are the files you asked for located:

```
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/collabd
```